# ¿Como puedo hacer en javascript un programa que en Java parece sencillo?

Tags: javascript

Soy muy novato en programar, he conseguido de forma relativamente sencilla (gracias a múltiples y claros ejemplos en internet) leer la respuesta de [dtweet](https://dweet.io/) y guardarla en una variable.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
package leerrespuestadedweet;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class LeerRespuestaDeDweet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String lineaDeDweet, mensajeDeDweet = "";
            URL verDweet = new URL("https://dweet.io/get/latest/dweet/for/my-thing-name");
            try (BufferedReader entradaDweet = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(verDweet.openStream()))) {
                while ((lineaDeDweet = entradaDweet.readLine()) != null){mensajeDeDweet += lineaDeDweet;}
                entradaDweet.close();
System.out.println(mensajeDeDweet);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(LeerRespuestaDeDweet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(LeerRespuestaDeDweet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Quiero hacer lo mismo dentro de un página web y pensé que sería posible con JavaScript (ya sé que no tiene nada que ver con Java). Probablememente es sencillo o debe hacerse directamente en HTML ...

En internet no encuentro nada. ¿Algún ejemplo?, ¿algún enlace que conozcáis y me pueda ayudar?.

Gracias por vuestra paciencia.

Comment: Para consumir una API desde JavaScript solo debes hacer una simple petición. Por lo general se usa AJAX; solo debe pasarse la URL y parámetros/cabeceras si son necesarios. Esa petición te devolverá la respuesta que envía la API. Si la respuesta es JSON, la conviertes a tal mediante [`JSON#parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse).

Comment: Mira esta librería https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios que, supongo yo, haría lo mismo que la librería `URL` de tu programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas tan rápidas, probaré con AJAX, el github que me comenta toledano es bastante complejo para mí, gracias igualmente.

Answer (score 2):

Un pequeño ejemplo con la libreria `JQuery` usando ajax.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://dweet.io/get/latest/dweet/for/my-thing-name",
  method: "GET"
}).done(function(response){
  $('.pa').html(response.this);
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="pa">Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: El asunto es "no hacer la tarea" de otros. No alimentemos este tipo de preguntas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por por el ejemplo, me ha servido para irme introduciendo en Javascript al igual que la página para principiantes con ejemplos https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get2.

Comment: Guz, con 57 años, nadie me pone tareas ni deberes, sólo soy un aficionado que andaba perdido, gracias, insisto, por tu aportación. En cuanto sepa como, daré este asunto por cerrado para que nadie pierda su tiempo.

Comment: @FBU, no importa la edad. El término "hacer la tarea" en programación se refiere a "no escribir código por otro" para que de esta manera, el interesado pueda investigar y **aprender** cómo se realiza. Me alegro que lo hayas logrado, esa era mi intención.

Comment: Curioso, no lo sabía, muchas gracias por el ahorro de Gelocatiles.

Answer (score 1):

Pues al final haciendo caso a la indicación de Guz, mediante AJAX y siguiendo el ejemplo de https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get2, he hallado rápidamente la forma de conseguir lo mismo que con el JAVA.

```
<script>
    var respuesta = "";
    function loadDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            respuesta = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = respuesta;
            }
        };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://dweet.io/get/latest/dweet/for/my-thing-name", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Me respondo a mí mismo por si le sirve a algún otro torpe como yo.
Gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Ves como solo era cuestión de investigar? No tomes los comentarios que se te hagan aquí, "a pecho" como se dice coloquialmente, me refiero a que **no se escriba** código desde  cero para otro, porque así no se contribuye en el aprendizaje como tal. Me alegra que lo hayas logrado. PD: ¿por qué `respuesta` es declarada fuera?

Comment: Cuando pienso en variables, lo hago pensando en su "alcance", tengo que "trabajar" esa variable como si fuera un String (sólo he usado el IDE de Arduino y el JAVA con Netbeans). Verás, estoy sacando mi ip pública con una ESP8266 y la dejo en dweet, a partir de ahí debería (en una página web que me hice en WIX) acceder desde internet a mi ESP8266 para decirle que debe hacer, en fin son jueguecitos de aficionado pero que se complican. Muchas gracias por el interés.

Comment: Ya veo. Te comento algo rápido que te ahorrará uno que otro dolor de cabeza. JavaScript es un lenguaje **asíncrono**. ¿Qué quiere decir ésto? Quiere decir que las instrucciones de JavaScript **no son siempre bloqueantes** como el de Java; es decir, si tu llamas a `loadDoc()` y en la siguiente línea imprimes `respuesta` verás que muchas veces `respuesta` sigue vacía. Esto se debe a que AJAX es una petición asíncrona, se ejecuta en **parelelo** al flujo principal, siendo incierto que en la siguiente línea tengas accesible el contenido en `respuesta`.

Comment: ¿Cómo te aseguras de obtener el valor de la petición AJAX una vez completada? En ediciones anteriores a ECMAScript 2015 (versión actual) se usaba un callback/closure, es decir, pasándole una función a otra para que se ejecute en cuanto la primera ha sido completada. En tu caso sería así: `if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) { cb(this.responseText); }`, donde `cb` es la función pasada por parámetro: `loadDoc(function (response) { console.log(response); });`.

Comment: Pues deberé tener en cuenta tu valiosa aportación, veo que estás muy puesto, recuerda que estoy empezando, poco a poco espero conseguir lo que me he propuesto. Es mi primera experiencia preguntando en Stackoverflow y me está pareciendo fabuloso, muchas gracias Guz.